# Spring mvc when editing , user can't validate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a user registration application in spring mvc.
When saving the user class, it normally validates the user and saves according to my UserValidator class, but when editing the same user, I can't validate in the same way.it goes to endless loop.
this is the case when saving

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "registration";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        userService.saveUser(userForm);
        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());
        LOGGER.info("user with username %s successfully registered", userForm.getUsername());
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

this one is the case  when editing

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/edit-user-{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable Long id, ModelMap model) {
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (!user.getUsername().equals(context.getUserPrincipal().getName())) {
            return "login";
        }
        model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "registration";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/edit-user-{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model, @PathVariable Long id) {
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + userForm.getFirstName() + " " + userForm.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        userService.updateUser(userForm);
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

anybody please help, what is wrong with this code, when I press the edit button, it does nothing, like it falls into endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem solved by changing the code

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       return "registration";
   }
```

to

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       return "forward:/registration";
   }
```